# SilverStripe using requirements() for each AJAX call

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using a JS script for UI purposes in the CMS area by using a decorator for `LeftAndMain`.

```
class LeftAndMainTweaks extends LeftAndMainExtension {
  public function init() {

    parent::init();

    // My JS script
    Requirements::javascript('mymodule/js/myscript.js');
  }
}
```

The script is loaded only **once** and not again for each AJAX call (like browsing through pages or ModelAdmin's) which breaks some of the JS functionalities.

**How do you force the an external JS script to be reloaded after each AJAX call?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to force reloading of scripts. Use entwine hooks instead.

A common pattern is to use `onmatch` and `onunmatch`, eg.

```
$('.my-selector').entwine({
    onmatch: function () {
        // don't forget to call this._super();
        this._super();

        // Do your stuff to initialize your component
    },

    onunmatch: function () {
        this._super();
        // clean up your component, unbind event listeners etc.
    }
});
```

If a view creates a node with the `.my-selector` class, the `onmatch` will be called and you can initialize your component there.

Since you didn't specify what exactly you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give better guidance. I think this is also a pretty good read, if you're new to entwine: https://www.bigfork.co.uk/takeaway/a-beginners-introduction-to-using-entwine-in-silverstripe